# Obtaining the frequency content of my data

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft, frequency-analysis

I have a time series data in a list of arrays called epoch. Here's a MWE of how it looks like:

```
import numpy as np
epoch = [(np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                    [4, 5, 6],
                    [7, 8, 9]]),
          np.array([100, 101, 102])),
         (np.array([[10, 11, 12, 13],
                    [14, 15, 16, 17],
                    [18, 19, 20, 21]]),
          np.array([103, 104, 105,106])),
         (np.array([[22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
                    [26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
                    [31, 32, 33, 34, 35]]),
          np.array([107, 108, 109, 110, 111]))
           ]
```

For every i, epoch[i][0] is the data and epoch [i][1] is the time corresponding to that data. Each epoch[i][0] contains data from 3 channels, or signals from 3 different sources. I would like to get the frequency content of each channel, from every epoch.

Here's what I did:

```
FFT_freq = []
for i in range(len(epoch)):
    chj_fftfreq = []
    chj_fftvals = []
    for j in range(3):
        chj_fftvals.append(np.absolute(np.fft.rfft(epoch[i][0][j])))
        chj_fftfreq.append(np.fft.rfftfreq(len(epoch[i][0][j])))
    mat = np.column_stack(chj_fftfreq)
    FFT_freq.append(mat)
```

However, this gives me a lot of repeated values when I apply the code to my actual data. Am I doing something wrong or the frequencies of the three channels in every epoch are the same?

Comment: you create `chj_fftvals` and never use it

Comment: Can I use np.fft.rfftfreq without using np.fft.rfft?

Comment: Why you could not? There is no hidden internal state in numpy that requires you to use `rfft` before using `rfftfreq`